# In Google Map Project Source not found exception shows in android

Tags: java, android

In Google Map, when I debug the project the errors come on this line: ArrayList directionPoint = md.getDirection(doc); and shows that Source not found in Library class ActivityThread.PerformLunchActivity() method.
//MainActivity Code Below:

```
public class FirstMap extends Activity {
GMapDirection md;
private GoogleMap mMap; 
LatLng fromPosition = new LatLng(13.687140112679154, 100.53525868803263);
LatLng toPosition = new LatLng(13.683660045847258, 100.53900808095932);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_firstmap);
    mMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        LatLng coordinates = new LatLng(13.685400079263206, 100.537133384495975);       
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinates, 18));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(fromPosition).title("Start"));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(toPosition).title("End"));
        md =  new GMapDirection();
        Document doc = md.getDocument(fromPosition, toPosition, GMapDirection.MODE_DRIVING);    
        ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = md.getDirection(doc);
        PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(Color.RED);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < directionPoint.size() ; i++) {          
            rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
        }
        mMap.addPolyline(rectLine);     
}
```

}

// Code of GMapDirection and getDirection() method:

```
    public class GMapDirection {
    public final static String MODE_DRIVING = "driving";
    public final static String MODE_WALKING = "walking";

    public GMapDirection() { }

    public Document getDocument(LatLng start, LatLng end, String mode){
        //see link for xml : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/
        String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?" 
                + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude  
                + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude 
                + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving";
        Log.d("GoogleMapsDirection", url);
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(in);
            return doc;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public ArrayList<LatLng> getDirection(Document doc) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3;
        ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
        if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
                nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

                Node locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "start_location"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

                locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "polyline"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "points"));
                ArrayList<LatLng> arr = decodePoly(latNode.getTextContent());
                for(int j = 0 ; j < arr.size() ; j++) {
                    listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(arr.get(j).latitude, arr.get(j).longitude));
                }

                locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
            }
        }

        return listGeopoints;   
    }

        private int getNodeIndex(NodeList nl, String nodename) {
            for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength() ; i++) {
                if(nl.item(i).getNodeName().equals(nodename))
                    return i;
            }
                return -1;
            }


        private ArrayList<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
            int lat = 0, lng = 0;
            while (index < len) {
                int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
                do {
                    b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                    result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                    shift += 5;
                } while (b >= 0x20);
                int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
                lat += dlat;
                shift = 0;
                result = 0;
                do {
                    b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                    result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                    shift += 5;
                } while (b >= 0x20);
                int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
                lng += dlng;

                LatLng position = new LatLng((double) lat / 1E5, (double) lng / 1E5);
                poly.add(position);
            }
            return poly;
        }
}
```

Comment: Post your logcat.so that can find what error is there exactly

Answer (score 0):

An example with I do:

Activity code:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v          = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location, container, false);
        googleMap       = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        setOptionsItem(R.drawable.ic_mobileedge_navto, new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                findDirections( ((ScreenLocation)getScreen()).getMap().getCenterLat(), ((ScreenLocation)getScreen()).getMap().getCenterLon(), GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING );
            }
        });

        MapsInitializer.initialize( getActivity().getApplicationContext() );

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position( new LatLng( ((ScreenLocation)getScreen()).getMap().getCenterLat(), ((ScreenLocation)getScreen()).getMap().getCenterLon()))
                .title(getString(R.string.event_location))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_mobileedge_navpoint)));

        // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng( ((ScreenLocation)getScreen()).getMap().getCenterLat(), ((ScreenLocation)getScreen()).getMap().getCenterLon()), 15));

        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12), 1000, null);

        return v;
    }


    public void findDirections( double toPositionDoubleLat, double toPositionDoubleLong, String mode)
    {
        new GetDirectionsAsyncTask(MapFragment.this).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, String.valueOf(toPositionDoubleLat), String.valueOf(toPositionDoubleLong), mode);
    }


// Function to Draw Lines in GMap
public void handleGetDirectionsResult(ArrayList directionPoints)
    {
        PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(10).color(getResources().getColor(R.color.location_line));

        for( Object l : directionPoints )
        {
            rectLine.add( (LatLng)l );
        }

        googleMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
    }
```

Asynctask:

```
public class GetDirectionsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Object, ArrayList>
{

    private MapFragment     activity;
    private Exception       exception;

    public GetDirectionsAsyncTask(MapFragment activity)
    {
        super();
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(ArrayList result)
    {

        if (exception == null)
        {
            activity.handleGetDirectionsResult( result );
        }
        else
        {
            processException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        String toLat    = params[0];
        String toLon    = params[1];
        String mode     = params[2];

        try
        {
            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)  activity.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            List<String> providers = lm.getProviders(true);

            /* Loop over the array backwards, and if you get an accurate location, then break out the loop*/
            Location location = null;

            for (int i=providers.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
                location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(i));
                if (location != null) break;
            }

            double latitude;
            double longitude;
            latitude                    = location.getLatitude();
            longitude                   = location.getLongitude();

            LatLng fromPosition         = new LatLng( latitude , longitude );
            LatLng toPosition           = new LatLng(Double.valueOf( toLat ), Double.valueOf( toLon));
            GMapV2Direction md          = new GMapV2Direction();
            Document doc                = md.getDocument(fromPosition, toPosition, mode);

            return md.getDirection(doc);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.e(e.toString());
            exception = e;
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void processException()
    {
        Debug.d("Error Getting Location");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this  -
While calling ParserTask Asyntask pass your url to asynctask -

```
    url1 = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"....;
    ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();
    // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
    parserTask.execute(url1);
```

ParserTask class -

```
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread        

        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject; 
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;                     

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);    
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            // Traversing through all the routes
            for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                    HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);                 

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng); 


                    points.add(position);                       
                }

                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(5);
                lineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);  

            }

            map.addPolyline(lineOptions);   
            for(int i=0;i<Dec.html_instructions.size();i++){
                sb.append((i+1)+". "+ Dec.html_instructions.get(i)+"<br>");
                //System.out.println("sb--"+sb);
            }
        }
```

DirectionsJSONParser -

```
public class DirectionsJSONParser {

    /** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list of lists containing latitude and longitude */
    public List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String,String>>>() ;
        JSONArray jRoutes = null;
        JSONArray jLegs = null;
        JSONArray jSteps = null;    

        try {           

            jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

            /** Traversing all routes */
            for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){            
                jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                /** Traversing all legs */
                for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){
                    Dec.distance=((JSONObject) ((JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).get("distance")).get("text").toString();
                    Dec.duration=((JSONObject) ((JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).get("duration")).get("text").toString();
                    Log.d("Distance",Dec.distance.toString());
                    jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                    /** Traversing all steps */
                    for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                        String polyline = "";
                        if((boolean)(((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).has("html_instructions")))
                        {
                            String html=(String)(((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("html_instructions"));
                            html=html.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");
                            Dec.html_instructions.add(html);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Dec.html_instructions.add("no html");
                        }
                        if((boolean)(((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).has("maneuver")))
                        {
                            String side=(String)(((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("maneuver"));
                            Dec.maneuver.add(side);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Dec.maneuver.add("No side");
                        }

                        Dec.dis.add((String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("distance")).get("text"));
                        Dec.dur.add((String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("duration")).get("text"));
                        Dec.starting_lat.add((Double)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("start_location")).get("lat"));
                        Dec.starting_long.add((Double)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("start_location")).get("lng"));
                        Dec.ending_lat.add((Double)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("end_location")).get("lat"));
                        Dec.ending_long.add((Double)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("end_location")).get("lng"));

                        polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                        /** Traversing all points */
                        for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).latitude) );
                            hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).longitude) );
                            path.add(hm);                       
                        }                               
                    }
                    routes.add(path);
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e){           
        }
        return routes;
    }   


    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                    (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }
}
```